# How to remove a rating of vendor based on an insertion calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently inserting a star rating of various vendors using the following formula
New

```
New Rating Value = ((Overall Rating * Total Rating) + New Calculated ) / Total Rating
```

where

```
   Overall Rating = Current Rating value
    Total Rating   = No of reviews (ratings) currently present
    New Calculated = The new star rating value the user specified
```

The above formula works for adding a new rating. My question is how would I remove a specific rating and return to the old value if I only have the `New Calculated` and the total Rating value (I wont have access to the earlier Overall Rating  ?

Comment: I think you want to ask this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have $$\frac {O\times T+N_c}T=N_r$$  yes?

Then, if you are given $N_r,N_c,T$ we get $$O=\frac {N_rT-N_c}T$$

Note:  I am not entirely clear on the definition of $T=$ Total Rating.  How is it the same even after you add a new rating?  Shouldn't it have increased by $1$?  Usually when you add a new element to a sample and seek to compute the new average given the old, you take into account that the sample size has increased by $1$.

Comment: The Total Rating is the no. of reviews. If we are removing a rating T would be T-1

Comment: What is Nr ? is it New rating ? How would i get the New Rating ? New rating is the value which we replaced when we added a new rating

Comment: $N_r$ is what you call New Rating Value.  If you don't have that (or some equivalent information) then you can't extract the old rating  My point is that, in your formula, I think the denominator ought to be $T+1$.

Comment: When adding a rating T=T+1 and when removing a rating T=T-1

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: Actually i do have the Nr.

Comment: Yes, I thought you did.